# What does 委屈你了 mean in this situation?

Tags: translation, idioms, politeness

Suppose your friend invites you to dinner. He prepares a dish that he knows is too spicy for you, but you're a good sport and try it anyway; it actually turns out to be quite tasty. He says 委屈你了.

"I have wronged you" and "Sorry to inconvenience you" both sound too dramatic in English. What would be a colloquially appropriate translation here?

Comment: Sorry to let you feel wronged. ?

Comment: 委屈你了 does not sound familiar to me in this context.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is overly BrE but a common turn of phrase is:

> sorry to put you out

or

> sorry to have put you out

That would be a fairly close equivalent of 委屈你了.

Comment: A bit odd in American English, but perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

May be “Thank you for your support and understanding”？

Comment: A little too formal, at least for American English.

Answer (score 1):

I think even the dish is tasty, but it is also very spicy, so your face are red and damp with sweat, we can imagine the scene.
So I think your friend was just joking and wanted to comfort you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

How about "thanks for taking  one" (literally thanks you for taking a bite, but it also imply: "take one for the team" )

> "[Take one for the team](https://www.yourdictionary.com/take-one-for-the-team)"
>
> (idiomatic, informal) To accept some chore or hardship for the sake of one's friends or colleagues.

Comment: In this case, he didn't really cause me any hardship at all. Even though I don't like spicy food, I happened to like that one dish. That's why he said 委屈你了in a half-serious, half-joking tone. I wouldn't say I took one for the team though, since there were only two of us and I didn't exactly do him any favors by eating it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: **sorry to make you go through this**?

"nurse a grievance" is probably a right phrase to interpret here.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with "Sorry about that...(whatever)".  It's vague enough yet understandable.